# Looping over results and changing a parameter after each loop

Tags: php, logic

I'm working with an API and I need to collect all companies ( approx. 500 ).. Now the API states that the maximum amount of request per page is 100

> Now i'm wondering how do i loop over these results, while also increasing the page number after the 100 results.. I have the following right now but it doesn't take the pages into account.

```
// 0 is the page number, this should increment after each iteration and then I should run this function 
$companies = API::getCompanies(100, 0);

foreach($companies as $company) {
    // do stuff here.
}
```

### unknown number of results

The number of companies should be dynamic, so it does'nt know how many pages of results there are, I was thinking about using a while operator to see if there's still data coming in? Is this the way to go?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This would fetch all the companies .

```
$page = 0;
while(true) {
    $companies = API::getCompanies(100, $page++);

    // Here i assume that when you get to the end of the list
    // the API should return an empty array/error message/exception etc ...
    // so check if this condition is met and finish the loop.

    if (!$companies) break;
    foreach($companies as $company) {
        // do stuff here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I forgot to add that the number of companies is dynamic.. So it should not know how many there are..